# Design pattern for microservice's client

Tags: java, design-patterns, spring-boot, microservices

I am using spring-boot to build client of microservice that would call a specific service depending on the params I will receive in my rest controller method.

I am using Java switch instruction like that :

```
    switch(param)
      case param1:
                 call service1;
      case param2:
                 call service2;

etc...
```

I would like to know if there is a specific design pattern that will help me to code this functionnality more sweety.

Thanks.

*(sorry for my bad english)*

Comment: You could try to use *Command pattern* or even *Strategy Pattern*. Or just an hashmap, as you have a *key* (your param) to point to an *URL* (your service call). It depends, you have to check more in detail which approach better fit your case.

Comment: @Mario, thanks I finally use Hashmap